# Updating a specific record in Ember Data without making HTTP calls?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js model called `emails`. This is what the file looks like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    label   : DS.attr('string'),
    primary : DS.attr('string'),
    email   : DS.attr('string')
});
```

I am fetching results from the server and pushing data in by doing something like:

```
this.store.createRecord('emails', {
    label: 'Foo',
    primary: true,
    email: foo@bar.com
});
```

I have a form that allows users to add new emails to the store. Once they add a new one, I am pushing it to the store using the above code.

There can only be one record in the store with the key `primary' set to`true`. When a user adds a new primary email, I need to manually edit any existing primary email to false and only then add the new email record.

I tried doing something like `this.store.peekAll('emails')` and parsing it but I can't seem to understand how to fetch only the record where `primary: true` and update it. How can I accomplish this?

Remember, I am not using the REST Adapter so I cannot query Ember Data like this: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-multiple-records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine Ember Data's `peekAll` and the Ember.Enumerable method `findBy` to get the record:

`var primary = this.store.peekAll('email').findBy('primary', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to filter the list of emails for that attribute:

```
emails = this.store.peekAll('email');
primaryEmails = emails.filter(function(email){
    return email.get('primary') === true;
  });
//because filter will return an array, hopefully of length 1:
primaryEmail = primaryEmails[0];
```